# $H_n(M|x;\ R)$ is isomorphic to $H_n(M|x)\otimes R$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

On pg. 235 of Hatchers's *Algebraic Topology* the author writes the following:

> Let $M$ be a topological manifold and $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $x\in M$ be arbitrary. Then there is a canonical isomorphism $$H_n(M, M-x;\ R)\cong H_n(M, M-x;\ \mathbf Z)\otimes_{\mathbf Z}R$$

I can see this isomorphism by using the universal coefficient theorem of homology. But Hatcher proves the UCT for homologies after he states the above fact. And Hatcher does not give a proof.

So there must be an easy way to see this. Can somebody please help out.